# About adjusting brightness for Sony Vaio E Series with Windows 7 Home basic 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, brightness

I have a Sony Vaio E Series laptop with Windows 7 Home basic. I need to adjust the brightness of the screen, but I could not find the option for adjusting the screen brightness. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have all drivers and OEM software installed?

Comment: Have you tried press and hold Fn and then tap either F5 (down) or F6 (up)? We need more info as to how you have tried to alter the brightness, e.g. using software or the keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness settings gone, how do I bring it back?](http://superuser.com/questions/400417/brightness-settings-gone-how-do-i-bring-it-back)

Comment: @Tog  In my `VGN-NW20EF' laptop `Fn + F3 or Fn + F4` is working fine for the sound, but `Fn + F5 or Fn + F6` not working for the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

Use the VAIO control center, and disable the automatic brightness adjustment.  There is a [tutorial here](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/tutorial/424206), and it is set like this:

[image: vaio control center]
<sup>(Click image for larger view)</sup>

I am assuming that you tried using the function <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with <kbd>F5</kbd> & <kbd>F6</kbd> and they didn't have any effect.

If you don't have the Vaio control center installed or running, and don't want to add it, then right-click on the desktop & choose "Graphics Properties ..." and you should be opened into the display driver's control center (i.e. on my Vaio that puts me in the "Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel");  chose "Color Enhancement" from there & you can manually adjust the brightness, contrast, etc. However, this method is a static setting.

[image: intel graphics control panel]
<sup>(Click image for larger view)</sup>

You can also adjust the brightness to a static setting for plugged-in and on-battery, using the granular power options in Windows 7: **Control Panel ➯ Power Options**.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was in another Super User question:
[Brightness settings gone, how do I bring it back?](https://superuser.com/questions/400417/brightness-settings-gone-how-do-i-bring-it-back)

Now I am able to adjust the screen brightness.

Comment: I have Sony `VGN-NW20EF` laptop and done above, but couldn't solve the issue. Earlier I could see bright adjust option under the Display settings at the control panel, but now can't see that option.